# Angular / Dart and Material Inputs: How to put a link into a checkbox label?

Tags: angular, dart, angular-material, angular2-dart, dart-angular-templates

Simple question: Is this somehow possible?

```
<material-checkbox [(ngModel)]="agbsAccepted" label='I have read <a href="/#/terms" target="_blank">the terms and conditions</a> and accept those.'></material-checkbox>
```

If I write it like this the HTML is parsed into a normal string. But if I write it do not use the label property its sometimes difficult to style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML in string interpolation bindings is not supported.
The `label` attribute is added using string interpolation

```
<div class="content">
  {{label}}
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

[material-checkbox template source](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2_components/blob/dedd4cb56dc931b76c282daa3c8f78856cb7e8ad/lib/src/components/material_checkbox/material_checkbox.html#L19-L22)

As you see in the template, projected context is supported though, therefore this should do what you want:

```
<material-checkbox [(ngModel)]="agbsAccepted">
  I have read <a href="/#/terms" target="_blank">the terms and conditions</a> and accept those.
</material-checkbox>
```